# Recycling views in custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm implementing a custom layout. It's a heterogenous grid and will look like the one below, except for the fact, that the tiles will be images with some text. Additionally it has an animation effect - each time the underlying data is changed (items added, removed, reordered) there's an animation, each tile moves to its new position. And this works perfectly.

The whole thing is inside a `ScrollView`. When user starts app, a few tiles (20 at most) appear. As he reaches the bottom of the scroll, new tiles get loaded. The tiles are `RelativeLayouts`.

**My question concerns the recycling of views.** Typical layouts which accept multiple subviews like `ListView` or `GridView` have a recycling mechanism. On scroll, when a view is not visible, it's recycled and it comes back when it's about to be seen by the user again.

Do I need to implement such a behaviour? What would happen if I don't? Is it even possible to implement it since I may have to animate the sub-views (also these which wouldn't be in the visible part of the layout) to their new positions when new data arrives.

Or maybe I should just recycle the bitmaps when they're outside the visible area? This is probably where I could hit an OutOfMemory, isn't it?

[image: Heterogenous Grid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd definitely recommend recycling, especially if the number of items is effectively unlimited.

Aside from memory issues which, like you say, will largely depend on handling of Bitmaps, not recycling will cause more chance of juddering when you load in more items. This is because more Views will need to be created - rather than recycled.

Implementing View recycling should be quite straightforward given you're using a custom layout, just keep a cache of Views and follow the Pattern similar to Android's Adapter class (i.e. `getView(int position, View convertView ..)`. When you need to animate a View from offscreen, you'll use `getView()` to get an unused View and update it to contain your model data (if you're not using MVC for this, I'd recommend it).

Comment: Thanks for responding! I don't have an idea on how to do the "new data animation" efficiently yet, but will work it out. Does recycling here mean only removing it from layout (`removeView(View)`) and keeping in some cache? And adding it when it's needed? Or is there something else I should do?

Comment: I think you can just set a View to visibility GONE instead of removing it (then VISIBLE when reusing it obviously), but your layout will need to ignore GONE Views.

Comment: Hmmm, I really don't think that setting visibility to gone is equivalent to recycling.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. By recycling do you mean to have just a few views (just those visible ones + few for error margin) and when they come of the screen set their visibility to GONE, re-use them with new data and show them again? My idea of recycling views was something like: remove the view from the layout, put it in some sort of a SparseArray (`RecycleBin` in `ListView`) and add it to the screen as soon as it may become visible. As a side note, I think that I have to handle scrolling myself, instead of using `ScrollView`, unfortunately

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can remove them and put them in a sparse array if you want, the key thing here is to re-use them, so either approach is fine. If you decide to set them to GONE, then when you need a new View you can run through all the child Views looking for ones set to GONE.

Comment: I searched for some solutions and I can see, that I'll have to implement a custom `AdapterView` for it to work properly. Extending a ViewGroup is not a good idea. Not sure yet how to handle the animation... Anyway, thanks for your help, I'll accept the answer in a few days if noone else replies.